# VueJS/Tailwind CSS/VITE: use env variables as colors for a Tailwind theme

Tags: vue.js, tailwind-css, vite

I have a VueJS setup with Vite, Tailwind CSS and postcss, and would like to define different colors using variables in a `.env.name` file so that I can apply different color themes depending where the code is deployed.

I tried with a `.env` file containing

```
VITE_COLOR="FF0000"
```

and an import within the `tailwind.config.js`

```js
...
theme: {
    colors: {
       primary: import.meta.env.COLOR
    }
}
...
```

However, I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use 'import.meta' outside a module

What do I have to change to get this to work or is there an even better method?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Tailwind config is CommonJS file (not module) so you cannot use ES6 features like `import`

You can install package called [dotenv](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dotenv)

```bash
npm i dotenv
```

Require it on top of your tailwind config file like

```js
require('dotenv').config()

module.exports = {/** */}
```

create color variable in `.env`. Note as we require it out of Vite's scope it may not be prefixed with `VITE_`

```
ANY_COLOR='#ffc8dd'
```

Now you can access it in tailwind config

```js
theme: {
    colors: {
       primary: process.env.ANY_COLOR
    }
}
```

This will work **BUT** if you change color in `.env` file you need to rebuild your styles again. If it is OK for you (one deployment - one color anyway) - fine. I personally would suggest another solution based on CSS variables - [link to CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/css-variables)

Define variable in CSS file or create `style` tag within `<head>` tag in `index.html`

```css
:root {
    --theme-color: #ffc8dd;
}
```

and in config

```js
theme: {
    colors: {
       primary: 'var(--theme-color)'
    }
}
```

And that's it - no extra packages, extra work and if you change CSS variable, changes will be applied on the fly - even in production as we are using CSS functionality