# How to get Vite environment variables in tailwind.config.cjs file

Tags: environment-variables, tailwind-css, vite

I can't figure out how I can grab the specific Vite environment variables in the `tailwind.config.cjs` file.

**.env.development**

```
VITE_TAILWIND_PRESET = preset_one
```

**tailwind.config.cjs**

```js
    /** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
    const presetFiles = {
        present_one: './src/styles/presets/one.js',
        present_two: './src/styles/presets/two.js',
    }
    
    console.log(import.meta.env)
    console.log(import.meta.env.VITE_TAILWIND_PRESET)
    
    module.exports = {
        content: [
            "./index.html",
            "./src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}",
        ],
        theme: {
            extend: {},
        },
        plugins: [
            require('@tailwindcss/forms'),
        ],
    }
```

The above code throws the error:

> console.log(import.meta.env): [vite] Internal server error: [postcss] Unexpected token (7:18)

If I change the code to `console.log(process.env)` I get all the environment variables except the VITE ones that I've added to the `.env.development` file.

To be clear, there is nothing wrong with the `.env.development` file. In my `vite.config.js` file the file is loaded correctly using

```js
    import { defineConfig, loadEnv } from 'vite';
    
    export default defineConfig(({ mode }) => {
        const env = loadEnv(mode, process.cwd())
        ...
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [VueJS/Tailwindcss/VITE use env variables as colors for tailwind theme](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73469689/vuejs-tailwindcss-vite-use-env-variables-as-colors-for-tailwind-theme)